# Rails/Paperclip absolute_path from form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip, nokogiri

I'm trying to save the `absolute_path` from the Paperclip file attached in a Rails form. I want to save it to the database for later use.

I read through the Paperclip docs and can't find anything that I think will work. Ruby has a solution for File abstraction in the [ruby-docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/File.html) that I was able to get working in terminal but I'm not sure how to implement it with Rails and Paperclip in a form.

Ultimately, the goal is to parse an XML file and use the file path to tell Paperclip where to find the images listed in the XML which are in the same folder.

I have 2 models BulkImport and BulkDownloads. BulkImport parses the xml file and creates each download in BulkDownloads.

XML snip:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<CUSTOMERS>
     <CUSTOMER>
          <FIRST_NAME>FIRST</FIRST_NAME>
          <LAST_NAME>LAST</LAST_NAME>
          <EMAIL>TEST@TESTEMAIL.COM</EMAIL>
          <CUSTOMER_ID>222222</CUSTOMER_ID>
          <WEB_PASSWORD>1234567</WEB_PASSWORD>
          <GALLERY_CODE>CODE</GALLERY_CODE>
     </CUSTOMER>
</CUSTOMERS>
```

BulkImports Model:

```
class BulkImport < ActiveRecord::Base
  require "open-uri"
  has_many :bulk_downloads, dependent: :destroy

  has_attached_file :doc
  validates_attachment_content_type :doc, 
                                presence: true,
                                content_type: ["application/xml", 
                                               "text/xml"],
                                message: "file must be in xml file format"

  def parse_file
    tempfile = File.open("#{doc.path}")
    file = Nokogiri::XML(tempfile)
    parse_xml(file)
  end

  def parse_xml(file)
    file.root.elements.each do |node|
       if node.node_name.eql? 'CUSTOMER'
         tmp_download = BulkDownload.new
         tmp_download.cust_id = node.xpath("CUSTOMER_ID").text
         tmp_download.webpassword = node.xpath("WEB_PASSWORD").text
         img = node.xpath("CUSTOMER_ID").text
         ## THIS IS THE PATH I WANT TO CUSTOMIZE BASED ON XML FILE LOCATION
         image_url = URI.parse("app/xml/#{img}.jpg").to_s
         tmp_download.attachment = open(image_url)
         tmp_download.save!
         self.bulk_downloads << tmp_download
       end
       save
    end
  end
end
```

BulkImport controller create action:

```
def create
   @bulk_import = BulkImport.new(bulk_import_params)

   respond_to do |format|
     if @bulk_import.save
       @bulk_import.parse_file
       format.html { redirect_to bulk_imports_path, notice: "#{@bulk_import.bulk_downloads.count} downloads were successfully created." }
       format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @bulk_import }
     else
       format.html { render :new }
       format.json { render json: @bulk_import.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
     end
   end
 end
```

I've tried queued_for_write[:original].path before save which returns the tmp file path for the xml doc and not the original url.

```
2.2.1 :007 > doc = bi.doc.queued_for_write[:original]
=> Paperclip::FileAdapter: testfile.xml
2.2.1 :008 > doc.path
=> "/var/folders/b_/6d4jhyxn0yd9mvv2bzvc67nw0000gn/T/9bc955dbd052ef51652e70a5104492e320150629-38408-m0q0zm.xml"
```

Comment: Show us the data you're working with, reduced to the bare minimum necessary for us to see the path to the data you're after. Also, show us the code you've written toward solving this, or explain what you've tried and why you think it won't work. As is, we could spend a lot of time shooting in the dark suggesting things you've already tried, which wastes both our times.

Comment: Please see code samples. Thanks for your help...